# Javascript to search images via Google

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm working on a uni project: we are making a webstite for restaurant reviews by programming a server in Java and then linking it to html via Rythm Engine.
Now, restaurant owners will have to be able to create their restaurant's page on the site, and I would like said page to include at least one picture of the place. Uploading an image would involve php, which is outside of the scope of this project (mainly focused on Java). I want to include a script in the html that searches Google for the restaurant name and just grabs one picture off the internet. I found a handy snippet for finding a somewhat random image, too bad the API is not working anymore. Who's willing to help?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1');
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    var search;

    //i suggest instead of this to make keywords list so first to pick random keyword than to do search and pick random image
    var keyword = 'mountains';

    function OnLoad()
    {
        search = new google.search.ImageSearch();

        search.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete, null);

        search.execute(keyword);
    }

    function searchComplete()
    {
        if (search.results && search.results.length > 0)
        {
            var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * search.results.length);

            //you will probably use jQuery and something like: $('body').css('background-image', "url('" + search.results[rnd]['url'] + "')");
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + search.results[rnd]['url'] + "')";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why _uploading an image would involve php_?

Comment: I meant letting the user upload his own image for the page, sorry if it was vague

Comment: If you are developing a Java web based application you can allow users to upload images to the server.

Comment: I'll look into that then, but it doesn't answer the question I asked